# About binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

1. I have been told that Nagelkerke should not be used in a model of binary logistic regression, but instead a R2 as a measure of goodness of fit. So, how can I apply R2 if I am not using a linear regression.
2. How can I compare 2 or 3 models of binary logistic regression? is there any software?

Thanks!

Comment: Best not to ask two separate questions in one post. I have proposed what I believe is a duplicate for your first question. Consider asking your second question in a separate post. If you do so, please specify whether your models are nested, which makes a difference. We likely won't concentrate on software, but on the underlying statistical theory.

Comment: Thanks, I will split my question in two posts